# Java regular expression for ending with *

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write regular expression in java to match alphanumeric string which can optionally have *. But if it contains * then it has to be at the end of that string. It can only contain one *

Below inputs should return `true`

```
abcd

abcd*

*
```

Where as below input should return `false` since it contains * which is not at the end of that string

```
abc*d
abcd**
```

I tried writing java program as shown below , but it is not working

```
public static void main(String[] a){
    String pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\*]$";
    String test = "abcd*";
    System.out.println(test.matches(pattern));
}
```

It return `true` for `abcd*` but not for `abcd` and `*`

Please let me know how to fix this regular expression. Thanks

Comment: `[\\*]` is redundant. Either use a character class so `*` has no special meaning (`[*]`), or use escape so `*` has no special meaning (`\\*`). Doing both works, but is excessive.

Comment: When using `matches()`, the `$` pattern is redundant.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, you are right. Thanks. It is now working with  [a-zA-Z0-9]*[*]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify that the trailing asterisk is optional by using a ?

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]*[*]?
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. But I also wanted regular expression to return true for *. I have edited my question now

Comment: Updated to check for 0 or more alphanumerics (*) instead of 1 or more (+).

Comment: Should be just `[a-zA-Z0-9]*\\*?` (or `[a-zA-Z0-9]*[*]?`), i.e. no need for both ``\\`` and `[]`, and no need for `$`.

Comment: Good point here and in question comments. Updated to remove escaping and terminal ($) check. @Andreas